# How do I merge days of the week using the UNION operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using this WITH method so that I can combine two SELECT statements.

The problem is that When I join the results using the UNION, it is duplicating the days and combining the time column. I need it the other way around.... for example: I am trying to select results on all Mondays that are equal to 14:00 and then another set of results that equal 16:00 and have those two display in separate columns next to each other.

An example of what this is currently giving me is below this SQL query.

```
USE Trading;
GO

WITH 
  ctetwo (CTEday, CTEtime) AS
  (
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime]) as Day,
        COUNT(M.[High] - M.[Low]) as Two  
    FROM dbo.MicroES M
        WHERE CONVERT(time, M.[DateTime]) = '14:00'
        AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,M.[Datetime]) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
        GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime])
  ),
    cteSix (CTEday, CTEtime) AS
  (
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime]) as Day,
        COUNT(M.[High] - M.[Low]) as Two  
    FROM dbo.MicroES M
        WHERE CONVERT(time, M.[DateTime]) = '18:00'
        AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,M.[Datetime]) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
        GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime])
  )

    select 
  --'Monday' AS 'Day',
    CTEday AS 'Day',
    CTEtime as TimeFour
   from ctetwo

   UNION ALL 

     select 
  --'Tuesday' AS 'Day',
    CTEday AS 'Day',
    CTEtime as TimeSix
   from cteSix

   ORDER BY Day
```

Day            TimeFour

Friday      15

Friday      17

Monday      13

Monday      19

Thursday    15

Thursday    18

Tuesday     16

Tuesday     16

Wednesday   18

Wednesday   18

Comment: Aside: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do that using a single select?

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime]) as [Day],
    COUNT(M.[High] - M.[Low]) as Two  
FROM dbo.MicroES M
WHERE CONVERT(time, M.[DateTime]) in ('14:00','18:00')
    AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,M.[Datetime]) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, M.[DateTime])
ORDER BY [Day],Two
```

Comment: THanks for your reply. I would like to see two separate columns next to each other. When I select '14:00' it should return a column of values and the '18:00' should return a separate column. I need to compare the columns side by side.